# How to select input content if there is only one error class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if there is **only one** div with an error class. And if so, I want to `.select()` the content of the input (that's in the in corresponding input class div).

How would I do such thing?

**My attempt** which does not work:

```
if($("div.addition").hasClass(".error").length === 0) {
    (this).parent().find('input').select();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text">
        <div>
            <div class="addition">Message message.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text">
        <div>
            <div class="addition">Message.</div>
        </div>
    <div class="input">
        <!-- So in this case this input's content will be selected -->
        <input type="text">
        <div>
            <div class="addition error">Error message.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that you're missing a closing `</div>` (for the second `div.input` tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Q3B/) that should do it - I mentioned as a comment to your post that you're missing a `</div>` tag, that is fixed in the fiddle - without it, the jquery selector matches two inputs. Outline of the js:

```
if ($('div.error').length === 1) {
    errorContent = $('div.error').parents('div.input').find('input').val();
    alert(errorContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plain JavaScript implementation. No need to use jQuery unless you're already using it.

```
var errors = document.getElementsByClassName('error');
if(errors.length === 1){
  //If there is one class with error
  var content = errors[0].innerHTML;
} else{
  //there is more than one error class.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check if there is only one div with an error class.

```
if ($("div.error").length === 1) {
    // Exactly one div with the class "error"
}
else {
    // Zero or more than one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery it can be done like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = $('.error');
    if(div.length){
    var val =  div.parents('.input:first').find('input').val();
    //val is the value of input
    }
});
```